# Help me identify this random plant sprout

Tags: houseplants, leaves, indoors

This plant started growing in the pot of a small Jade Plant I received about two weeks ago. I the Jade in store bought dirt that I purchased well over a year ago and had stored in Ziploc bags. It also doesn't look like anything I currently have or have tried to grow before. Any information will be helpful. Thank you.

Edit: New picture added with new true leaves.[image][image: Plant sprout]

[image: Side view]

Comment: The first two leaves on a plant are usually cotyledons and not true leaves. Hence the only true leaf of the plan is the one at the very tip, and it looks like it hasn't matured fully. I'd be curious if someone can identify it! Perhaps try to post an update photo in the future, when you have a few more true leaves?

Comment: I currently have it under a grow light with my other plants and a second true leaf is beginning to take shape. I'll post more once there's at least three leaves.

Comment: I think I managed to identify the plant for anyone interested. I believe it is a Black Locust Tree. Really not sure how I got the seed, but it is considered invasive in my state, so maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: legume was my first guess so sure that would fit your guess.  :)